# MySQL Error 29. SQL not using correct file path

Tags: mysql

Working on using the `LOAD DATE INFILE` syntax to import my csv files into my database. Using windows 10.

Originally when using this syntax I was getting **ERROR 1290** which I resolved by adding: `secure-file-priv = "" to the .ini file.`

I no longer get ERROR 1290 but when i use:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Users\ovoJa\Downloads\VEN01_562.csv'  
INTO TABLE    venom  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I get this ERROR 29:

> File 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\UsersovoJaDownloadsVEN01_562.csv' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)

Why is it still looking in the Programdata file for the .csv file?

Comment: try to use this C:\\Users\\ovoJa\\Downloads\\VEN01_562.csv

Comment: that worked for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use this `C:\\Users\\ovoJa\\Downloads\\VEN01_562.csv`